# Prevent content (files) upload to cpanel

Tags: cpanel

I am new to Management System. Now I need to control a website. Some days ago, someone hack it — not SQL injection, just file change / new files upload.

I need to know the how can I prevent it; I want to learn.

Please, can someone give me some suggestions?

Comment: Maybe google can come to your aide?

Comment: There are several links, i can't find any useful links, So i need suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent this, You need to update your server security with the mod_security, Mod_security is web server firewall so you will have to install and upadte mod_sec rules on your server to prevent this,

Also, Update your site scripts and plugin and themes which you are using for your site.

Use strong password for your cPanel, FTP and site admin panel

Also, Check WHM >> Security Center >> Security Advisor and fix all the Warning which you will get in that scan report.

Install maldet on your server and scan your all user home directory and remove infected files from your account.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, i will make it.